# writing a module that will be bundled with nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, node-modules

I'm writing an npm module that exports a simple SDK and react components.

Currently, its not being bundled with the frontend code in nextjs. When I log the contents of the module in the server-side code it prints correctly, however it is `undefined` client-side.

Since a primary thing I am exporting is react components, its important that the code is bundled client-side.

I'm not using any node-specific features (fs etc) but it looks like its still being eliminated from the bundle.

Is there a specific format I need to use to compile my module, or where can I find documentation on how nextjs decides which modules to drop during code-splitting?

tsconfig for package

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */,
    "strictNullChecks": true /* Enable strict null checks. */,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true /* Enable strict checking of function types. */,
    "noUnusedLocals": true /* Report errors on unused locals. */,
    "noUnusedParameters": true /* Report errors on unused parameters. */,
    "noImplicitReturns": true /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/tsc/",
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "lib": ["ES6", "DOM"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.test.ts"]
}
```